# Listview will not refresh after retrieving data from shared preferences

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have a listview of ringtones with a bookmark icon in each row inside my main Fragment. And I have another fragment to show the favorited ringtones inside it.(when a bookmark icon inside my main Fragment is clicked, that specific row data will be saved into shared preferences and will add to favorite Fragment).

Now my problem is when I click on an Item to make it as favorite it will not immediately show in my favorite Fragment. I tried all this:

```
listView.requestLayout();
listView.refreshDrawableState();
listView.invalidate();
listView.invalidateViews();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

None of them works. Or I just have to detach and attach favorite Fragment or close app and reopen it.

Can you help me, please?

This is how I add an Item to my shared preferences inside **Main Fragment**

```
@Override
public boolean favOnClick(int position , View v) {
    ProductLight product = soundList.get(position);
    ImageView button = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.favImageHive);
    String tag = button.getTag().toString();
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
        sharedPreference.addFavorite(product);
        snackS("Added to Favorites");
        button.setTag("red");
        button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
    } else {
        sharedPreference.removeFavorite(product);
        button.setTag("grey");
        button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
        snackS("Removed from Favorites");
    }
    return true;
}
```

And I get my favorite list from shared preferences in **Favorite Fragment** like this:

```
private List<ProductLight> soundList = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();
.
.
.

soundList = sharedPreference.getFavorites();
adapter = new CustomLightAdapter(activity, soundList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Shared Preferences**

```
public class SharedPreference_light {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Light_Products";
public static final String FAVORITES = "Favorite_Tones_Light";

SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Gson gson = new Gson();

public SharedPreference_light(Context context) {
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
}

// This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
public void saveFavorites(List<ProductLight> favorites) {
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
    editor.apply();
}

public void addFavorite(ProductLight product) {
    List <ProductLight> favorites = getFavorites();
    if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();
    favorites.add(product);
    saveFavorites(favorites);
    Log.w("addPrefLog", favorites.toString());
}

public void removeFavorite(ProductLight product) {
    ArrayList <ProductLight> favorites = getFavorites();
    if (favorites != null) {
        favorites.remove(product);
        saveFavorites(favorites);
    }
}

public ArrayList <ProductLight> getFavorites() {
    List<ProductLight> favorites;
    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        ProductLight[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, ProductLight[].class);
        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList <ProductLight> (favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList <ProductLight> ) favorites;
  }
}
```

Comment: Call method of favourite fragment from list fragment on onclick of fav button which will update the list of fav items

Comment: editor.apply() is an asynchronous function, maybe u can call an interface listener in onSharedPreferenceChanged. Or use editor.commit() instead??

Comment: @FarukItsDO Yes, but commit() will slow down my listview scroll if I save too many Items. I tried it by the way and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you save the data into the shared preference, you want the list to be updated. This can be done using the shared preference change listener.
Implement the SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the main Fragment and override the onSharedPreferenceChanged() method. Make sure to register the shared preference change listener in the oncreate() method, 
i.e. sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); 
And deregister in the onDestroy().

So when you add data into shared preference, you will get callback in the onSharedPreferenceChanged(). So add your logic in this method to refresh your list.

Comment: I think my shared preferences is working fine. Because (consider I have an Item in Favorite Fragment and is showing in that listview) Now in my main Fragment if I click to unmark that Item, The bookmark icon in favorite Fragment will turn into unchecked but the Item itself is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a list to ListView Adapter

`adapter = new CustomLightAdapter(activity, soundList)    //soundList should be a global variable;`

When making changes the soundList should be updated as well. And then calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will make that change reflected in ListView